# A small planar set containing a large family of curves

Tags: measure-theory, plane-geometry

A beautiful construction by Besicovitch and Rado [1] produces an astounding example of a compact connected plane set of measure zero containing circles of all radii $r\in(0,1]$.

A corollary to a theorem proved in [2] states that there exists a nowhere-dense compact connected plane set containing a translated image of the boundary of every compact convex set of diameter at most one.

**Question:** Is there a compact connected plane set of measure zero containing a translated image of the boundary of every compact convex set of diameter at most one?

[1] Besicovitch, A. S.; Rado, R.,  *J. London Math. Soc.* **43** (1968) 717–719, MR0229779

[2] Holsztyński, W.; Kuperberg, W.; Mycielski, J.,  *Houston J. Math.* **3** (1977), no. 4, 475–476, MR0461433